# Specify required type after a filter method on an array

Tags: typescript

I would like to make a separation between two arrays. In one array, the object does not have a specific value. In the other, it should have a string.

```js
interface Relation<T> {
  href: URL;
  notAlways: T;
}

// This response sometimes has a string or a null value in the 'notAlways' key.
const response: { relations: Relation<string | null>[] } = await request(paramUrl);

const doesNotHaveIt: Relation<null>[] = response.relations.filter(
  (relation: Relation<string | null>) => !relation.notAlways,
);
// Error: Type 'Relation<string | null>' is not assignable to type 'Relation<null>

const doesHaveIt: Relation<string> = response.relations.filter(
  (relation: Relation<string | null>) => relation.notAlways
);
// Error: Type 'Relation<string | null>' is not assignable to type 'Relation<string>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a predicates (passed to `filter`) a [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
const doesNotHaveIt: Relation<null>[] = response.relations.filter(
    (relation: Relation<string | null>): relation is Relation<null> => !relation.notAlways,
);

const doesHaveIt: Relation<string>[] = response.relations.filter(
    (relation: Relation<string | null>): relation is Relation<string> => !!relation.notAlways
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQDZzMA9iAHgBUA%20ZAbwChkbkALKCGALmQFVUAZAbmtpFxgAghgDucAJ4BnVkV4BfSpQAmEBFkbIE%20KWGSMpABx0RW5fZmx4QMtJZz4CuqKADmyAD7IQAVwwYSAG0AXWR5XkptGz1lXAgpADlBAAk4ADcIAEkwVnQsB0JffyDQgF4LIxMAOkZ86ykqmGAMSCgACj4aNtqrfFz7aycwFxB3LyKAgEpWHoLkYCk7OscJslKyAEJZ6yqBYTFJKQAaSkmIqN1kWPjUjOz%205cJnNxLkcoNjGwgagZ1G5taHVoyG6vxAD16T2Gbk83j8UxmYPmizykKGI1ca02WzBu0EInE0lO3CAA)

---

Explicit variable annotation can be removed now as it is properly inferred:

```
const doesNotHaveIt = response.relations.filter(
    (relation: Relation<string | null>): relation is Relation<null> => !relation.notAlways,
); // doesNotHaveIt is Relation<null>[]
```

Comment: nice one (Also with the double bang)